# Tree Select UI coding challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I recently took OA that I bombed. What would be the most efficient way to solve this question? Any inputs are highly appreciated.

I'm new to the community as well, so I apology if my question is not structured well.

A `TreeSelect` is a UI input component whose model is a tree where each node consists of a checkbox and a label.

A node's checkbox can be in 1 of 3 states reflecting the selected status of the sub-tree rooted at the node:

- checked: ALL the leaf nodes in the sub-tree are selected.
- partially-checked: SOME (but not ALL) of the leaf nodes in the sub-tree are selected.
- unchecked: NONE of the leaf nodes in the sub-tree are selected.

Each node's checkbox can be clicked to change its status:

- if a checkbox is checked, clicking on it would un-select all the leaf nodes in the sub-tree.
- if a checkbox is partially-checked, clicking on it would select all the leaf nodes in the sub-tree.
- if a checkbox is unchecked, clicking on it would select all the leaf nodes in the sub-tree.

The tree is provided as '/' separated paths to leaf nodes. Assume every node's name is unique in the tree.**

For example:

```js
 [ 
    'A/B/D',
    'A/B/E', 
    'A/B/F', 
    'A/C', 
    'X/Y', 
    'X/Z',
]
```

It would result in the following tree:

```
-A
  -B
    -D
    -E
    -F
  -C
-X
  -Y
  -Z
```

A series of clicks on nodes is given as an array of node's names. For example, the clicks `['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']` would look like:

```
-A
  -B
    -D
    -E
    -F
  -C
-X
  -Y
  -Z
```

Your task is to create a `renderTreeSelect` function which takes paths and clicks as arguments and returns a rendering of the tree as a string. Render each node including the following:
-for each level of indentation.
-`[v], [o], [ ]` for the checkbox (representing checked, partially-checked, unchecked respectively)
-The node's name

Child nodes of a parent should be sorted by name. Again, you can assume every node's name is unique in a tree.

Sample input:

The following input is provided with 6 paths and 4 click

```
 6 
 A/B/F 
 A/B/D 
 A/B/E 
 A/C 
 X/Y 
 X/Z 
 4
 A
 B
 D
 E
```

This will be parsed to the following values:

```js
 paths = [ 
            'A/B/F',
            'A/B/D', 
            'A/B/E', 
            'A/C', 
            'X/Y', 
            'X/Z',
];
clicks = [
            'A', 
            'B', 
            'D', 
            'E'
        ];
```

The expected result of calling `renderTreeSelect(paths, clicks)` should be:

```
  [o]A
  .[o]B 
  ..[v]D 
  ..[v]E 
  ..[]F 
  .[v]C 
  []X 
  .[]Y 
  .[]Z
```

Here is the start point:

```js
/*
Complete the 'renderTreeSelect' function below.
The function is expected to return a STRING. The function accepts following parameters:
1. STRING_ARRAY paths 2. STRING_ARRAY clicks
*/

 function renderTreeSelect(paths, clicks) {

 }
```

My thought process :-

> It was an online coding challenge so I do not have the exact code that I wrote.
> So what I recollect doing was i created a Node where each node was like `Node {value: {checked:"", partiallyChecked:"", unchecked:""}, children:[List of nodes], Map:{Map for each child node path} }`.
>
> What i tried to do was once the tree was constructed, trying to propagate the
> values of the action for a node in the tree to its parent. Once we know what the
> actions are, we can just parse through the tree and build the string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you haven't done so, please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here. This question is missing one major component.  It is reasonably written, although you perhaps include too much detail from your source question (we could probably start with `paths` and `clicks`.) The critical factor not included: some demonstration of your own effort.  Did you try and fail? Then show some code. If not, explain your thoughts processes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was an online coding challenge so i do not have the exact code that i wrote. So What I recollect doing was i created a Node where each node was like Node {value: {checked:"", partiallyChecked:"", unchecked:""}, children:[List of nodes], Map:{Map for each child node path} } What i tried to do was once the tree was constructed, trying to propagate the values of the action for a node in the tree to its parent.Once we know what the actions are, we can just parse through the tree and build the string. This was my thought process. Even a starter idea would do.

Comment: It makes sense.  Next time (or even this one: [edit]) please include this information in the question.  I find this interesting, partly because of the doubly-linked nature of the nodes.  I find it much easier to work with structures where nodes know about *either* their children or their parents but not *both*.  Here that seems to be necessary, and might require a different type of data structure than I usually use.  Because of this, I will try to find some time to work on this soon.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sure I will update the information as you have mentioned. I really appreciate your time on this one.

Answer (score 2):

### Description

Here is one approach:  We build a tree structure where each node has a `name`, a possibly-empty array of `children`, and a `state`.  For the `state`, here we use strings: `'c'` for *checked*, `'u'` for *unchecked* and `'p'` for *partially checked*;  this might be better using enums or some other construct.

To click a node, it's easy enough to check it's state, and set it to ***c**hecked* if it's not already checked, and to ***u**nchecked* if it is, and then to pass that value down to its descendants through a simpler recursion.

But then we also need to ask the parent node to update based on its children, to capture the possible *partially checked* state based.  This means we want an event analog of the web's `capture`-then-`bubble` event system.

We can write `capture` and `bubble` functions easily enough, except that
the structure we've described doesn't handle that, because a node doesn't know it's parent.  We will fix this by including an `addParents` function that recurses through an object added a reference on each node to its parent.

Here I find myself deviating from my usual coding style.  I tend to work with immutable data.  Usually, if I were to handle the `capture` phase of such a click event, I would return a *new* tree, sharing what parts of the old one I can, but creating new nodes where necessary.  Here, I end up using a mutable data structure, because I couldn't see any good way to do both the `capture` and `bubble` efficiently on a mutable tree.  I'm not happy about this, and may later try to write a new version that addresses this concern.

But once we're beyond that, `capture` and `bubble` are simple enough, recurring respectively through `children` and `parent`.  `bubble` has to do a bit more work, as it needs to check whether all children are `checked`, in which case, we make the parent `checked`, whether they are all `unchecked` and we make the parent `unchecked`, or a mix, and we make it `partially checked.`  But the code is fairly simple.

At that point we can write a quick wrapper than handles an array of clicks, updating the tree with every one, and some fairly simple code to display the tree, using a `depth` helper parameter, which we increment as we recur.  Because the data structure we use includes a `_root` node, we need to do a little work to remove the root node and a level of indentation.

### Code

The code looks like this:

```js
// *******************************************
// Utility functions
// *******************************************

// Yields all the nodes in a preorder traversal of a tree, 
// with descendents of a node in its `children` array property.
function * traverse (node) {
  yield node
  for (let n of node .children || []) {
    yield * traverse (n)
  }
}

// Find the first node in such a tree matching a predicate, or `undefined`
const deepFind = (pred) => (obj) => {
  for (let node of traverse (obj)) {
    if (pred (node)) {return node} 
  }
}

// Supplies a predicate to the above to find the first node with a given `name`
const findNode = (target) => 
  deepFind (({name}) => name == target)


// *******************************************
// helpers for building our data structure
// *******************************************

// Creates a tree from a list of `/`-separated path names, such as `foo/bar/baz`
// Each node looks like {name: 'foo', state: 'u', children: [...]}
const buildTree = (paths) => paths 
  .map  (p => p .split ('/'))
  .reduce (
    (node, path) => addPath (path) (node),
    {name: '_root', state: 'u', children: []}
  )

// Adds a node to such a tree, given a `path`, creating missing nodes as needed
const addPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (node) => {
  let child = node .children .find (c => c .name == p) || addNode (p) (node)
  if (ps .length) {
    addPath (ps) (child)
  }
  return node
}

// Adds a child node to a given node for that same tree structure 
const addNode = (name) => (node) => {
  const child = {name, state: 'u', children: []}
  node .children .push (child)
  // The following is inefficient, but as the rest of this code is pretty horrible...
  node .children .sort (({name: n1}, {name: n2}) => n1 < n2 ? -1 : n1 > n2 ? 1 : 0)
  return child
}

// Adds `parent` nodes (`null` for the root) to the nodes of such a tree
// Once called our structure is not cyclic, and not easy to display
const addParents = (node, parent = null) => {
  node .parent = parent
  node .children .forEach (child => addParents (child, node))
  return node
}


// *******************************************
// helpers to manipulate our data structure
// *******************************************

// Performs a series of clicks against nodes in a tree 
const clickAll = (node) => (names) => {
  names .forEach (click (node))
  return node 
}

// Clicks a specific node, cascading to children, bubbling to ancestors
const click = (node) => (name) => {
  const child = findNode (name) (node)
  if (child) {
    capture (child .state == "c" ? "u" : "c") (child)
    bubble (child)
  }
  return node
}

// Given a state, apply it to a node and all its children
const capture = (state) => (node) => {
  node .state = state
  node .children .forEach (capture (state))
}

// Correct the state of a node based on its children, 
// and then do the same with ancestors
const bubble = (node) => {
  if (node == null) {return}
  node .state = node .children .length == 0
    ? node .state
  : node .children .every (({state}) => state == 'c') 
    ? 'c'
  : node .children .every (({state}) => state == 'u') 
    ? 'u'
  : 'p'
  bubble (node .parent)
}


// *******************************************
// helpers to display data structure
// *******************************************

// Turns a tree into an array of depth-specific strings such as 
const rows = (node, depth = 0, s = node.state) => [
  `${'.' .repeat (depth)}[${s == 'c' ? 'v' : s == 'p' ? 'o' : ''}]${node .name}`,
  ...(node .children || []). flatMap (c => rows (c, depth + 1))
]

// Turns such rows into the output format, by removing the root
// node and one level of indentation, then combinging them into 
// a single newline-demlimited string.  (This is very specific to problem.)
const display = (node) => 
  rows (node) .slice (1) .map (s => s .slice (1)) .join('\n')


// *******************************************
// main function
// *******************************************

// Uses all the above to build the base tree, add parent nodes
// to it, perform all the clicks, and stringifies it in the requested format.
const renderTreeSelect = (paths, clicks) => 
  display (clickAll (addParents (buildTree (paths))) (clicks))


// *******************************************
// sample data
// *******************************************

const paths = ['A/B/F', 'A/B/D', 'A/B/E', 'A/C', 'X/Y', 'X/Z']
const clicks = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']


// *******************************************
// demo
// *******************************************

console .log (renderTreeSelect (paths, clicks))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Development

#### Using a hard-coded data structure

To build this I started in the middle.  I designed the data structure I would use, hand-crafted to look like this:

```js
const tree = {name: '_root', state: 'u', children: [
  {name: 'A', state: 'u', children: [
    {name: 'B', state: 'u', children: [
      {name: 'D', state: 'u', children: []},
      {name: 'E', state: 'u', children: []},
      {name: 'F', state: 'u', children: []},
    ]},
    {name: 'C', state: 'u', children: []},
  ]},
  {name: 'X', state: 'u', children: [
    {name: 'Y', state: 'u', children: []},
    {name: 'Z', state: 'u', children: []},    
  ]},
]}
```

Then I wrote the `addParents` function.  I also included a `removeParents` one for debugging purposes; it got rid of the cyclical structure and gave me something easier to `console .log`, but it wasn't necessary in the final code.

I needed to be able find a Node in the tree, and I reused tools that I keep handy: `deepFind` searches for the first node in a tree that matches the predicate supplied.  It lets me write `findNode` as a very simple function.  `deepFind` depends on `traverse`, a generator function that yields every node in a postorder traversal of the tree.

This let me write the simple `capture` and the slightly more complex `bubble` in a straightforward manner.  And then the display code is another simpler recursion.  `rows` turns the modified tree into

```js
[
    "[o]_root",
    ".[o]A",
    "..[o]B",
    "...[]F",
    "...[v]D",
    "...[v]E",
    "..[v]C",
    ".[]X",
    "..[]Y",
    "..[]Z"
]
```

And `display` strips off the first row, removes a level of indentation from the rest and then joins them with new-lines to return the requested output.  (Note that even here we don't do a `console .log`.  We leave that for the calling code.)

#### Generating that data structure

At this point, we have everything we need except for converting our input into our data structure.

So we write a `buildTree` function.  Originally, I thought I could do a quick modification of the tools I [use often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate) to convert, say:

```js
{
  'foo/bar/baz': 1,
  'foo/bar/qux': 2,
  'corge': 3,
  'grault/warbly': 4
}
```

into something like

```js
{
    foo: {
        bar: {
            baz: 1,
            qux: 2
        }
    },
    corge: 3,
    grault: {
        warbly: 4
    }
}
```

While I probably still can do that, the sorting of the `children` implied by the input and output requirements seemed to make that more difficult, and I wrote some one-off code for this.  Again, I'm not very happy with this code, and it seems to me that we could drastically improve it, but at this point, I had everything working and was ready to put it aside.  If I do come back to it, I will probably also rewrite `buildTree` and maybe eliminate the helpers `addPath` and `addNode`.  This really should be simpler.

#### Putting it together

Now we have working code for everything.  We just need to write our main function.  But that turns out to be just a matter of calling the existing functions with our inputs:

```js
const renderTreeSelect = (paths, clicks) => 
  display (clickAll (addParents (buildTree (paths))) (clicks))
```

### Possible fixes and enhancements

As noted along the way, this is not code I'm proud of.  I think a better version might address some or all of these problems:

- We use magic strings to represent our `checked`, `unchecked`, and `partially checked` states.  It would be useful to employ a better construct.
- `buildTree` seems way too complicated, and it still doesn't integrate `addParent`... which really shouldn't need a separate step.
- There's also a silly inefficiency in `addNode`, re-sorting the nodes every time one is added.  This should probably be done at the end, after the tree is built.
- But this biggest concern is the mutable design.  In the time I was willing to dedicate to this interesting problem, I couldn't come up with a simple and efficient immutable model that handled the `click` call.  If I do take this back up, it would be primarily to fix this.

Comment: very impressive @Scott Sauyet, you should create a small youtube video about how you built this solution.

Comment: Thanks, @Jim41Mavs.  I never did go back to this, and am still unhappy with the mutable state.  If I ever do and manage to fix that, perhaps I'll try.  Cheers!